# I am trying to update version of angular from 8 to 9

Tags: angular, version, upgrade

[image] I have go throgh the steps mentioned on https://update.angular.io/. after completing the process I got these errors. please help me

Comment: Which errors? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

try this: in your app or library module

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

and add it to imports array

```
imports: [CommonModule]
```

Comment: I have made the changes. but getting same error

Comment: try closing vscode and open again :) sometimes vscode throws error when there's none

Answer (score 0):

Check if component imported/exported properly and added to declarations